# Helcim Gateway API - Missing or invalid field amount cannot be zero

Tags: payment-gateway

I am creating a simple purchase transaction with amount = 00.00 but its giving me error missing or invalid field value - amount. Actually I just want to tokenize my credit card that's why amount is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send **allowZeroAmount=1** if you want to do a zero dollar authorization to get a card token:
https://www.helcim.com/support/article/123-helcim-gateway-api-optional-variables/